# How do I delete an upload from an order?

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a situation where the customer uploads a file with their order, using a file field attached to the order. The only way currently on our site to delete the artwork is to delete the order or delete files through FTP.

Neither of these are ideal, it would be best to have an automatic rule set up that deletes all uploads after a certain amount of time, say 1 week after the order, but does not delete the order as these need to be kept in record.

Either this or a manual way to achieve this, I have had a look around for modules but there doesn't seem to be one to achieve this.